# Abinitio explicit fixed point

Tags: decimal, etl, sqldatatypes, fixed-point, ab-initio

I have a DDL in my abinitio ETL code as follows,
decimal (“\x01”.6) AMOUNT = NULL (“”)

What does this mean? Is it a round off to 6 decimals or truncation to 6 decimals?
Eg, 123.4567889 = 123.456788 or 123.456789 ?

Thanks in advance.